# Nest.js caching: Error: "null" is not a cacheable value

Tags: node.js, typescript, caching, redis, nestjs

I have the following `cache-config.service.ts` with `isCacheableValue` function as [here](https://github.com/node-cache-manager/node-cache-manager#specifying-what-to-cache-in-wrap-function):

```
...

@Injectable()
export class CacheConfigService implements CacheOptionsFactory {
  host: string;
  ...

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService<RedisConfig, true>) {
    this.host = this.configService.getOrThrow<string>('redis.host', {
      infer: true,
    });
    ...
  }

  createCacheOptions(): CacheModuleOptions<ClientOpts> {
    return {
      store: redisStore,
      host: this.host,
      isCacheableValue(value) {
        return value !== null && value !== false && value !== undefined;
      },
    };
  }
}
```

But it crashes on `null` returned value.

For example, when I call get request on non-existing user at `/users/999`, it return `null` and server is crashed with error: `Error: "null" is not a cacheable value`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since you have this condition, value !== null, then it wont allow you to cache null. Right?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't cache `null` values, but why the app crashes?

Comment: try `return !!value`

Comment: This issue has been resolved with the new (latest) version of `node-redis@4.5.1`.